# Django - using Many-to-Many horizontal interface outside of admin

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many

I'm working in a form with a m2m field. I want that this field looks like the horizontal interface of the django admin site... ¿how i can do it?

thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from django import forms
from .models import Person


class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    some_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Person.objects.all(), widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Person", False, attrs={'rows':'2'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

You will also need to include the Javascript and CSS used in the admin. Here's an [example](http://jayapal-d.blogspot.com/2009/08/reuse-django-admin-filteredselectmultip.html)

Comment: To add on to this, you can also use the FilteredSelectMultiple widget in the widgets property in the Meta class as an alternative. Still have to include the CSS and JavaScript, however.

Adding the plus button from the Admin interface is a bit more painful

Comment: Cool, I like that approach better! Much cleaner

Comment: @msc could you renew your **exapmle** link or include example inside your answer because your link is outdated