# Django 1.10 - how-to: Many-to-Many horizontal interface

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

As in [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16203287/django-using-many-to-many-horizontal-interface-outside-of-admin), I would like to get  in my own template the same  horizontal interface as you get in the admin pages with

`class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal   = ('MyM2M',)`

I understand that I have to use the FilteredSelectMultiple widget. However the given example there seems to be outdated.
What are the necessary js/css for django 1.10, jquery 2.2.4?

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the FilteredSelectMultiple widget. It is indeed built for the particular structure of the admin page. It is probably possible to adapt it for another page structure, but it may be difficult to make a "universal" answer out of it. 
I have resigned, and give a try to Select2.js. Works like a charm.